# How can I access a value nested within two levels of array in a JSON Response using C#?

Tags: c#, json, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON Response which looks something like this. [image: JSONResponse]

I am trying to access the value "Hello". I am using Newtonsoft.JSON package to parse and serialize my data. I am able to access all the values, except "Hello" .

Below is a small example of how I dealt with single level arrays like menu3:

```
JArray dataArr = (JArray)joResponse["menu3"];     //joResponse is my JSONresponse
string[] datalist = dataArr.ToObject<string[]>(); //gave me 1234 and 5678 as string list
```

Any ideas/logic/resource/example would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier for you if you'd create a model class for the JSON response and deserialized the string using it. For example:

```
public class MyModel {
    public string Menu1 { get; set; }
    public string Menu2 { get; set; }
    public List<int> Menu3 { get; set; }
    public string Menu4 { get; set; }
    public List<string> Menu5 { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the class you receive your JSON string:

```
    var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(jsonString);
    // Access any property through myObj object
    var menu1 = myObj.Menu1;
```

Comment: I keep getting the following error.
"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Value"

Comment: @CodeBreaker please edit your question with the code you're currently using and a sample JSON